# What is the diff of retruning something "directly" of not?

Tags: javascript, return

Today I've discovered something that I wasn't aware.

```
function forecast(arr) {
   return arr.slice(2, 4)
}

//["warm", "sunny"]

forecast(['cold', 'rainy', 'warm', 'sunny', 'cool', 'thunderstorms']));
```

and

```
function forecast(arr) {
   arr.slice(2, 4)
   return arr
}
//  ["cold", "rainy", "warm", "sunny", "cool", "thunderstorms"]

forecast(['cold', 'rainy', 'warm', 'sunny', 'cool', 'thunderstorms']));
```

To my understanding so far, they should log the same thing.

What is the fundamental difference between the above two?

Comment: Think about what `slice` returns, and what it does to the original array.

Comment: returns a copy of the original array...

Comment: So, if it *returns* the copy, what happens if you don't use the return value like in the second version? Think about what `arr` is in second version. Is it the copy?

Comment: No it's not the copy. It's the original array. But this is confusing because I me the first instance of arr after the return statement should be arr.slice() and not the original arr due to the closure of the function. No? Am I getting this confused?

Comment: You never reassign `arr`, so no. The returned array is not automatically put into `arr`. If `slice` altered the original array instead of returning a copy, your second version would behave as you expect (but the first wouldn't unless `slice` *also* returned the array). Values returned from a function are never automatically put into a variable (except in a browser console).

Comment: Read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice *"The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included) where begin and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified."* Reading that, you can see you are returning what is returned from the slice method and the array. So no it should not return the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not and should not produce the same result:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
return arr.slice(2, 4)
```

This will return the result of the `slice` operation, which as per the link provided is an array containing the result of the `slice` operation.

```
   arr.slice(2, 4)
   return arr
```

This simply returns the array argument `arr` as originally provided. The result of the `slice` call is unused and discarded.

Exactly what happens in each situation will differ depending on what functions you call on `arr`. As an example/thought experiment, it would be possible to redefine `slice` so that it mutates the original array, and in this case both examples will return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
return arr.slice(2, 4);
// Could be written as
var slicedArray = arr.slice(2, 4);
return slicedArray;
//You return a new array returned by slice()

arr.slice(2, 4);
return arr
// Could be written as
var slicedArray = arr.slice(2, 4);
return arr;
//You are returning the original array, not the new one returned by slice()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually all the string/array related functions don't directly edit the actual object. They make a copy of the object and do things on them.

To quote from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included) where begin and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

Most of the languages work for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method doesn't really change your original array but just creates a shallow copy of the array with the changes made by the `slice()` method to it.

In your first snippet, you are returning the shallow copy of the array with the slice method applied to it whereas in the second snippet, you are just returning the original array which was never changed or mutated by the `slice()` method in the first place.

---

To make you understand what I mean by "***slice()*** is immutable", let me compare it with another method like say, [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) which is a mutable method.

As opposed to the [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method which is an immutable method (doesn't mutate/change original data), if you were to use a mutable method like say, the [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method, then the original data get modified too as can be seen in the following example:

```js
const array1 = ["happy", "new", "year", "stackoverflow"];
const array2 = ["happy", "new", "year", "stackoverflow"];

// will just create a new array called sliceArr and wont change array1
let sliceArr = array1.slice(2, 4);

// will create a new array called popArray with just the last item of array2 in it as well as change array2 with the last item removed
let popArray = array2.pop();

console.log(array1);
console.log(sliceArr);
console.log(array2);
console.log(popArray);
```

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't I be returning the sliced arr in the second case due to the scope chain? isn't arr.slice() the first to come in the chain after the original array?

Comment: @TiagoRuivo Yes, it does come first in the chain but the `slice()` method did not change `"arr"`. It just utilised `"arr"` to give you something else similar to `"arr"`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: .pop() is changing the original, therefore the log to array2 is changed... that makes sense. I guess I got confused with the scope chain and the closures...

Comment: I mean it is related with the scope chain too which you would see if you would console log `arr2` before you pop it in the above example, but the main reason for you getting different results is because you are returning some kind of a clone of `arr` in your first snippet. You never actually returned `arr`. Whereas, in the second snippet, you returned the original array and not the clone with the changes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Method `.slice()` does return a **new** array, it doesn't modify the given array. In the first example, you return a newly created array, in the second example you do ignore returned from `.slice()` method value